# Confusion on Do Carmo's Riemannian geometry chapter 0 proposition 3.7

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In Do Carmo's *Riemannian geometry* chapter 0 proposition 3.7, the author proves that every immersion is locally an embedding as follows:

[image]

[image]

The goal is to prove that there exists a neighborhood $V\subseteq M_1$ such that the restriction $\varphi|_V$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. From the proof, I guess that the author tries to prove that such restriction is in fact a diffeomorphism onto its image thus a homeomorphism. However, there are some subtle points in the last part of the proof I found hard to resolve.

First, when the author defines $\tilde{V}=W_1\cap U_1$ in the last paragraph, I guess that he in fact wants to define $\tilde{V}=W_1\cap (U_1\times \{(\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{k \ \text{copies}})\})$, right? Else, rigorously speaking, $\tilde{V}$ is simply an empty set.

Also, I deem that when he claims that $\phi|_\tilde{V}=\tilde{\varphi}|_\tilde{V}$, he actually wants to claim $\phi|_\tilde{V}=\tilde{\varphi}|_{\Pi(\tilde{V})}$, where $\tilde{V}$ is defined in the above paragraph and $\Pi$ is the natural projection map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is my reasoning correct? Else I found the expression in the book undefined.

Lastly, and most confusingly, how can he claim that $x_2\circ\tilde{\varphi}\circ x_1^{-1}$: $V\to\varphi(V)$ to be a diffeomorphism by two existing facts that $\phi|_\tilde{V}=\tilde{\varphi}|_{\Pi(\tilde{V})}$ and $\phi_1|_{W_1}$ is a diffeomorphism? To get his claim that $x_2\circ\tilde{\varphi}\circ x_1^{-1}$: $V\to\varphi(V)$ is a diffeomorphism, it basically requires $\tilde{\varphi}|_{\Pi(\tilde{V})}$: $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ to be a diffeomorphism. But the domain of $\tilde{\varphi}$ and $\phi$ are not the same dimension, how can I get his claim? Any details for the proof at this part are appreciated.

Comment: Guilleman and Pollack’s Differential Topology does a nice job of proving this- the local immersion theorem

Comment: @CharlieFrohman, Hi, I am new to smooth manifolds. I have seen that the local immersion theorem says that in some local coordinates $\tilde{\varphi}(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, 0, 0, ..., 0)$, how does this connect to this theorem?

Comment: Your second paragraph after the insert makes the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to this problem is to replace "diffeomorphism" in the original proof with "homeomorphism", and since an embedding is just by definition an immersion that is also a homeomorphism onto its image, the proof will still be complete and we don't need the strong result of diffeomorphism.

First, since $\phi|_{W_1}: W_1 \to W_2$ is a diffeomorphism, it's a homeomorphism, then by restricting $\phi|_{W_1}$ to $\tilde{V}\subseteq W_1$ (as how we define it in the text of the problem, not in the original proof), we obtain a homeomorphism onto the image as $\phi|_{\tilde{V}}: \tilde{V} \to \phi|_{\tilde{V}}\left(\tilde{V}\right)$ by passing both sides to the subspace topologies. Then, the projection map $\Pi: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ restricted to $\tilde{V}$, that is $\Pi|_{\tilde{V}}: \tilde{V} \to \Pi|_{\tilde{V}}\left(\tilde{V}\right)$, can be checked to be a homeomorphism onto its image with the appropriate subspace topologies and it is easy to see that $\phi|_{\tilde{V}}\circ\Pi|_{\tilde{V}}^{-1}=\tilde{\varphi}|_{\Pi|_{\tilde{V}}\left(\tilde{V}\right)}$. Now, Let $V=x\left(\Pi|_{\tilde{V}}\left(\tilde{V}\right)\right)$, we thus have
$$\varphi|_{V}=x_2\circ\phi|_{\tilde{V}}\circ\Pi|_{\tilde{V}}^{-1}\circ x_1|_{V}^{-1}$$ to be a homeomorphism onto its image since it's the compositions of homeomorphism.

The problem with diffeomorphism is that it is unsure that $\varphi|_{V}(V)$ is an open set and differentiability may not be defined.